# #VALUE! Error when trying to use the Filter function to filter on mutiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

| original_name | match_name_0 | score_0 | match_index_0 | match_name_1 | score_1 | match_index_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AGI Partners, LLC | agi partners llc | 100 | 5273 | agi partners llc | 100 | 5273 |
| AXA Investment Managers S.A. | axa investment managers sa | 100 | 17995 | axa investment managers sa | 100 | 17995 |
| Aberdeen Asset Management PLC | aberdeen asset management inc | 100 | 2123 | aberdeen asset management plc esop | 100 | 2128 |
| Acharya Capital | karya capital | 63.66124359 | 105080 | hara capital | 62.29887861 | 84903 |

I want to filter this range to return all values if the column name contains "match_name" and the original name matches a name in column A. The filter range will be different sizes, so I've also added an ifstatment to get rid of empty values

this is my formula:

```
=FILTER(S1:Y5, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("match_name", $S$1:$Y$1)) * ($S$1:S$5=A2) * (IF(S1:Y5<>"", 1, 0)))
```

however, no matter what I do - i keep getting an error. I've tried breaking out everything up until the filter and it contains the same number of rows and columns as the filter range.

Comment: some of the cell reference in the include part of the filter is 2 dimensions (`$S$1:$Y$1`) while another is 1 dimension (`$s$1:S$5`). That mixing could be the cause.

Comment: i tried changing the 1 demension part to two dimensions: so S1:s5=A2 to S1:Y5=A2 and still no luck

Comment: 2010 and 2007 do not have FILTER.  are those tags accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the return can be a 2D array, all the checks must be a 1D array and all must be the same size and shape and also must have either the same number of rows or the same number of columns as the return array.

So in you case you will want to do nested FILTERS:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(S1:Y5,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("match_name",S1:Y1))),S1:S5="AGI Partners, LLC")&""
```

Now it first filters to the correct columns then it filters that result to the correct row.

[image]

As to the empty cells in the output.  They will remain, because FILTER will not return a jagged result set.

Comment: this is great  can i ask what the purpose of the &"" at the end of the formula is? and are you saying the formula will work regardless of if there are blank rows? b/c the data set will be variable length so I want to include an extra 20-30 columns and 100 or so rows

Comment: yes it will work with blank rows so you can do a range 30 x 100 and it will only return those that have the value in column A and the value in the top row.  The &"" turns the blanks to blanks otherwise they return 0.

Comment: Thank you - I was actually just messing with this a bit more and trying to use Unique on the entire formula to only extract the unique values that are returned, do you have any idea why it wouldn't seem to have any impact?

Comment: With it returning a 2d array Unique will not do a line by line or column by column removal.  It will look at the whole row or whole column of the entire array for duplicates not cell by cell.  If just want a unique list (one Column) then use TOCOL on the 2D array and wrap that in UNIQUE.

Comment: you're a wizard Scott Craner

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the final result (not the interims, though one would think they "would follow" so to speak) must be a single row of 1's and 0's for `FILTER` to accept them. So {1,0,0,1} but not {1;0;0;1} as the latter would be four rows. (Notice the semi-colons in the latter vs. the commas in the former.)

As to handling the rows issue in the comparison to A2, you can simply wrap the range in a `TRANSPOSE` function to turn its output from rows to columns so that a real (as in useful) multiplication can occur. But even there, the differing sizes (five elements vs. the seven elements in the example range of S1:Y1) mean you'll get N/A errors in the internal array that Excel creates as it calculates and so you'd need perhaps an `IFERROR` to trap those and put in 0's.

But then the mismatch in what you are doing in the search in the header row vs. the comparison to A2 in the column S part... there's no match there, so the header row calculation telling you columns 2 and 5 are acceptable does not match in any way the result of the A2 comparisons. They simply cannot be used like this as any "correct" result would only be correct in the sense that a painting of a clock is "right twice a day."

What you really need to do is `IF` comparisons for those two pieces of data. As in `IF("the header match fails", "", IF("the A2 matching fails", "", do this))`.

For the header match, the current formula works to a point, but not in the above `IF(IF` approach. For that you'd need to wrap it with something like `SUM` and if the result is 0, no header labels match, else at least one does. (For what you describe, WHICH ones match doesn't matter.)

But using `XMATCH` with a search string like "match_name*" and setting the `match_mode" to "2" (wildcard searches) is much shorter/cleaner/easier to understand.

For the "do this" part of my `IF(IF` mentioned above, you'd then do a simple `FILTER` with the criteria part not being quite how you'd expect to provide. Instead, use `SEQUENCE` and `COLUMNS` like so:

```
SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(S1:Y1),1,0)
```

which will provide an array constant of 1's (include the column) for as many columns as there are.

For the range to `FILTER` in the above, including the header row is not necessary and the matching up above will not include it anyway. If you must have it (as your columns might vary), provide for it separately. A simple `INDEX` with the range the header row, extended way out to include any number of columns that is reasonable (assuming there's nothing to the right of them!), the row parameter a "1", and the column parameter being a `SEQUENCE` and `COLUMNS` like above would do nicely.

What you are currently doing will never be fixable so you must seek a different kind of solution.